# Building GMM using SIDEKIT 1.2

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, gaussian, gmm, sidekit

I have a 2 dimensional data in the form of a text file. I have to build a GMM based on this data using Sidekit 1.2.

Which function should I use to estimate the parameters of the Gaussian model (Mean, covariance matrix, weighted average etc.)

Can you please provide a small example with your own set of (x,y) data and build a GMM using that ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sidekit is a toolkit built mainly for the task of speaker recognition, and its framework (as other similar toolkits) relies on the training data consisting of audio files in the formats .wav, .sph or raw PCM. 
If you're just building a GMM and don't plan to use it for speaker recognition experiments, I would recommend using another toolkit for general statistical purposes ([scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) might be a good choice).

If you do plan to do speaker recognition tasks, you will have to some initial work on your data. If your text-data is some form of speaker data, you could convert it to the appropriate format. For example, if the y part is raw audio, convert it to wav-files. If y is cepstral features or other features, store it in h5.-format. After doing this, you can build a GMM for speaker recognition tasks by following the [tutorials](http://lium.univ-lemans.fr/sidekit/tutorial/rsr2015_gmm_ubm.html) on the Sidekit homepage.

Comment: Correction: You do not necessarily have to store features in .h5 formats, but it makes things easier. You can use the function mixture.EM_uniform to train a GMM on numpy-arrays of data.

Comment: (1/3)
@Jørgen A 
I created a numpy 2D array h=[x,y] ; where x is a 1d array of 500 x observations and similarly y is a 1d array of 500 y observations.

Now I used the function EM_uniform as :

 >>> ubm = sidekit.Mixture()
>>> ubm.EM_uniform(cep=h,distrib_nb=1024,iteration_min=3,iteration_max=10,llk_gain=0.01,do_init=True)

I'm getting the following error :

Comment: (2/3) Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/kishalaya97/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sidekit/mixture.py", line 748, in EM_uniform
    self._init_uniform(cep, distrib_nb)
  File "/home/kishalaya97/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sidekit/mixture.py", line 816, in _init_uniform
    self._compute_all()
  File "/home/kishalaya97/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sidekit/mixture.py", line 393, in _compute_all
    self.A = (numpy.square(self.mu) * self.invcov).sum(1) - 2.0 * (numpy.log(self.w) + numpy.log(self.cst))

Comment: (3/3)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1024,500) (1024,0)

Comment: @KD97 A possible solution to this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895460/training-ubm-with-sidekit-from-custom-data/44290934#44290934